# nHibernate 1.2 Lazy loading nested objects lost after passing entity as method parameter

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate

We have a WCF service which does some operation on Oracle Database using nHibernate 1.2
We have a method handling the request, where Transaction is opened before, and closed after that method (lets call it HandleRequest).

In this HandleRequest method I load an object from DB. Then I call a method UpdateSomeStuff(object new_stuff, object entity).
In that method when I try to access nested objects of this entity like Person.Address.StreetName I get error "NHibernate.LazyInitializationException: Could not initialize proxy - the owning Session was closed."

If I however access this same property outside Update method, in the HandleRequest, everything goes fine. That Update Method is in the same class as HandleRequest.

Here's some artificial code illustrating this situation.

```
public Response Request(Request request)
{
    Response result = null;

    SessionManagerFactory.SessionManager.HandleSessionStart();
    if(!SessionManagerFactory.SessionManager.TransactionExists())
        SessionManagerFactory.SessionManager.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        result = HandleRequest(request);
        SessionManagerFactory.SessionManager.CommitTransaction();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SessionManagerFactory.SessionManager.RollbackTransaction();
        log.Error(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        SessionManagerFactory.SessionManager.HandleSessionEnd();
    }

    return result;
}

public MessageResponse HandleRequest(Request pRequest)
{
    Person person = SessionManagerFactory.SessionManager.Session.Load(typeof(Person), pRequest.PersonId);
    UpdateAddress(person,pRequest.NewAddress);

    person.Address.StreetName = pRequest.NewAddress.StreetName; // <-- No exception here, work fine.
}

private void UpdateAddress(Person person, Address newAddress)
{
    person.Address.StreetName = newAddress.StreetName; // <-- Exception here !
}
```

Of course I do either UpdateAddress, or the other assignment, not these two at once.

And if I debug this method and break before UpdateAddress(..) method, and preview entity's address within VisualStudio, this method goes then as expected.

*EDIT: Changed code example to show Transaction Begin/End*

Comment: Can anyone provide any help?

Answer (score 0):

The session is being closed before the UpdateAddress method is called. When you use Intellisense to preview the property value, it is lazy loaded at that time. Carefully trace your code to see where this is happening. If it's a multi-threaded environment, the session may be closed by another thread. This commonly occurs in ASP.NET when using a poorly implemented session-per-request pattern.

Comment: I've put some more code to show sesssion/transaction start and end